# Java File - Append pre-defined filename to a user-defined directory

Tags: java, file, io

I have a program that creates multiple output files e.g. daily_results.txt, overall_results.txt etc.

I want to allow the user to specify the directory that these files will be saved to using JFileChooser.

So if the user selected the directory they wanted their output to be saved to as "C:\temp\". What is the best way to append daily_results.txt to that file object. Is there a more elegant way to do this other than:

```
File file = new File(userDirectory.getPath() + "daily_results.txt");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies!

I think this can quite easily be accomplished with the JFileChoosers setSelectedFile method.